# Interface and Implementation in Separate Assemblies Using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two assemblies; `AssemblyWithInterface` and `AssemblyWithClass`. In `AssemblyWithInterface` I have an interface called `IDoSomething` which is implemented by `TheClass` in `AssemblyWithClass`. (`AssemblyWithClass` references `AssemblyWithInterface`.)

In `AssemblyWithInterface` I want to create instances of the class from `AssemblyWithClass` using reflection:

```
var theAssembly = Assembly.Load("Company.AssemblyWithClass, { FQN... }");
var theConcreteClass = theAssembly.CreateInstance("Company.AssemblyWithClass.TheClass");
```

The assembly loads fine and the instance is created as a `TheConcreteClass`.

However, I'm unable to cast `theConcreteClass` to its implementing interface. I get an `InvalidCastException` here:

```
var theConcreteClassInterfaced = (IDoSomething)theConcreteClass;
```

And

```
var isAssignable = typeof(IDoSomething).IsAssignableFrom(theConcreteClass.GetType();
```

is False.

What am I missing? (The goal is to have a command pattern-styled ability to add commands implementing the `IDoSomething` to the `AssemblyWithClass` and be able to execute them in `AssemblyWithInterface` without changing code in the `AssemblyWithInterface`.)

Platform is .NET 3.5 (can't use dynamic).

**Update:**
The background for this question (to explain why I'm not complying to DIP) is that I have a legacy ASP.NET-application contained in one large assembly. I want to create a plugin assembly which can call into various parts of the legacy assembly to perform montoring and some automated tasks. I don't want any additional dependencies (references to other assemblies) added to the legacy assembly. The idea is to implement a hook in the legacy assembly (a new special page and a IPlugInOperation), add a montoring page with a corresponding code behind. Have the code behind execute various IPlugInOperations (drawing an interface to allow the admin to specify parameters to use for executing code in the legacy assembly). The PlugIn Assembly must reference the legacy assembly and the legacy assembly uses reflection to list and allow the admin to excute the various implementations of IPlugInOperation contained in the PlugIn Assembly.

Answer (score 2):

The interfaces should not care about implementations.

Refactor and move all logic to a third assembly.

**Update:**

*Specification assembly*

- public interface ICommand
- public interface ICommandFactory

*Class assembly (references specification)*

- internal class CreateUserCommand : ICommand
- public class CommandFactory : ICommandFactory

*Application assembly (references both)*

```
public class Program
{
    private ICommandFactory _commandFactory;

    public static void Main(string[] argv)
    {
        // this is the only line that is really dependent of a specific
        // implementation.
        _commandFactory = new TheSpecificImplementationAssembly.CommandFactory();

        ICommand command = _commandFactory.Create("CreateUser");
        command.Execute();
    }
}
```

**Update2**

Most modern solutions uses an inversion of control container to take care of the mapping between interfaces and implementations.

The other solution is to have a small set of factories which is used to create implementations for specific interfaces. In  this case I would also use factory method pattern to let aggregate roots be able to create child aggregates. For instance, the class `Order` would have a method called `CreateOrderLine` which would return a `IOrderLine` object.

Comment: But that is what I'm doing. I want to dynamically load all "Commands" from AssemblyWithClasses (the Low-Level Implementation) and treat them as their Interfaces in AssemblyWithInterface (the High-Level implementation).

Comment: @antirysm: AssebmlyWithInterface should not be aware of interface implementation. The code `Assembly.Load(AssemblyWithClass)` is wrong because you are hardcoding a definite assembly and implemetation class to an interface assembly, when you should use a third assembly like jgauffin suggested.

Comment: @Boris B. - We will make the AssemblyWithClass to load a configuration setting thereby "injecting" the entire assembly into AssemblyWithInterface. A third assembly would mean that AssemblyWithInterface needs to reference the AssemblyWithClass if I'm not mistaken. That is not possible, I don't want to add any referenced dependencies to AssemblyWithInterface. If I have both the interface and the implementation in a third assembly I can't see how I would be able to execute the "commands" in the AssemblyWithInterface.

Comment: No. A third assembly would load both the specification and the implementation assembly. The third assembly can at any time switch from your class assembly to any other assembly that got an implementation for the interface assembly. That's the whole point of separating interfaces from implementations.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can understand. If we switch to the Command Pattern: I have an "ICommand" and "CommandImpl" in AssemblyCommands. How would I go about executing the "CommandImpl" (treating it as an "ICommand") from AssemblyExecuting without adding a reference from AssemblyExecuting to AssemblyCommands? How can AssemblyExecuting know what an "ICommand" is?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer (+1) and your time. (I would normally use some IoC container for this, but this is a legacy application.) But the problem is that I can't add any references from the "Application assembly" because that would create dependencies that I don't want. I want to be able to deploy "Command assemblies" on the fly whereas redeploying the "Application assembly" is more difficult. That's why I need the interface in the "Application assembly".

Answer (score 0):

You have a kind of circular reference here, which is definitely not ideal, but it should be possible to do what you're after.  Take a look at [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx).  I suspect what's happening is that reflecting to instantiate the class is causing the system to load an extra copy of your original interface assembly, so that the interface type it's implementing is no longer the same type that you have statically referenced.  By implementing AssemblyResolve, you can search the list of loaded assemblies using [AppDomain.GetAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx), returning the one with a matching name.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
    private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().
                     FirstOrDefault(assembly => assembly.FullName == args.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I suspect something fishy with the environment (ASP.NET). Just doing a Assembly.LoadFrom from a Command Line targetting a DLL on the harddrive worked fine.

Comment: @jguaffin, you cannot have a circular dependency when performing static compilation, but this is loading an Assembly via reflection at runtime, which is allowed to reference assemblies that are already loaded.  Because there is no statically typed dependency, everything is already compiled and there is no problem.  The prohibition against circular dependencies is purely for the compiler; that's only because the compiler requires Type information, which doesn't exist until the referenced assembly is compiled.

Comment: @antirysm, I've run into this problem before when loading assemblies dynamically.  You can end up with odd things like retrieving TypeConverters loading a copy of an assembly, resulting in bizarre errors.  There is no prohibition against the loading the same assembly multiple times into an AppDomain, so this is something to watch out for.

Comment: @antirysm, If you're using ASP.NET, you may have an issue with shadowing going on, where the assembly that's being loaded is being loaded from a shadow directory.  This can allow replacement of the underlying assembly files without disturbing code that's already running.  In a case like this, the AssemblyResolve should still fix your problem, but you have to be careful how you find your 'plugin' to load.  I haven't worked much with this, but I recall there are some settings required in the AppDomain to make sure loading an assembly uses the proper shadowing.

Comment: @Dan Bryant - many thanks for the explanation of the "fishy" parts. I've done some experimenting using just a Console App without running into any of the problems. I'm going to try things out with your code tomorow. (Will update my question with the background...)